# What are the Major differences between PSX and 3DS version of Dragon Quest VII

Tags: version-differences, dragon-quest-series

I recently purchased the 3DS remake of Dragon Quest VII. I've noticed a few things while playing through it that are different than the Dragon Warrior VII PSone release in the mid 2000's. What exactly are the major changes or additions to the 3DS version compared to the PS one version.

[image: Dragon Warrior VII 3DS cover]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a nice list on gamefaqs someone posted that lists all the changes and additions between the PSX and 3DS version.

**Additions**

- Lithograph system
- Extra bonus dungeon
- Secret character

  > Kiefer
- New weapons and armor

Changes

- Monster park functions as the gateway for the Lithograph system.
- Monster hearts can be dropped before monster park opens.
- Human classes have reduced job point requirements.
- Some skills now are only usable in the class that they were learned in.
- Monsters have empty spaces filled out with skills.
- Battles take place in standard 1st person when actions are being selected, and switches to a 3rd person isometric view that shifts the camera depending on the action.
- Some shops are altered and re-balanced.
- The world map/boat/flying maps are more in line with the DQ8 and 9 changes. And like DQ9, enemies appear on screen.
- Human classes now have special models that appear in battle.
- Township was altered and streamlined.
- Casinos were altered slightly.

Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/688276-dragon-quest-vii-fragments-of-the-forgotten-past/69380016